# How do I add a new line to a richtextbox without making the last line blank?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm making a log system for a program im creating and I currently have it to where it does this:

```
void outToLog(string output)
{
    logRichTextBox.AppendText(output + "\r\n");
    logRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

But it ends up outputting the last line of the `RichTextBox` as blank (because I'm using `\n`) and I want the last line to just be whatever the output was, not a blank line. An alternative was for me to put the `"\r\n"` at the beginning, but this just has the same affect except its at the beginning of the `RichTextBox`.

help? thanks

Comment: Please don't create your own logging framework: use NLog. For how to use a richtextbox, don't mind this comment ;)

Comment: unfortunately, programming is to each its own, I dont want to use NLog. Im not creating my own logging framework. I'm simply outputting things to a rich text box if you want to call that my "framework".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Append the text after the newline.

```
void outToLog(string output)
{
    logRichTextBox.AppendText("\r\n" + output);
    logRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

If you don't want the newline at the start, check the TextBox for empty text and only add the `\r\n` when the TextBox is not empty.

```
void outToLog(string output)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(logRichTextBox.Text))
    {
        logRichTextBox.AppendText("\r\n" + output);
    }
    else
    {
        logRichTextBox.AppendText(output);
    }
    logRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Comment: User stated he already tried this: "An alternative was for me to put the "\r\n" at the beginning, but this just has the same affect except its at the beginning of the richtextbox."

Comment: Try just "\r". That works for me. "\r\n" and "\n" on the other hand gives me a blank line between.

Answer (score 9):

Eh, why not *check*? If text box is *empty* - just put the output, but if text box is *not empty*, add a *new line* and then append the the output.

```
void outToLog(string output)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(logRichTextBox.Text)) 
        logRichTextBox.AppendText(output);
    else
        logRichTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + output);

    logRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
}
```